# Best way to position textView at a particular height inside of a Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a Layout that contains an svg and a textview.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/svg"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/shape"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Example Image]

How can I configure this layout so that the textView containing the number is always positioned inside the crosshair-like gap in the svg?

Additionally, how can I make it so if I resize the container (same ratios) that everything else elegantly maintains positioning?

Comment: convert the svg to xml drawable, get the height of upper hair and place your textview with that margin top and center horizontal attributes. (not entirely sure though, you can try it)

Comment: you can use a LinearLayout + weights, or any layout + programmatically-calculated padding, or ConstraintLayout+constraints, which is the cleanest way I believe. Can't show the example, as I don't use ConstraintLayout yet.

Comment: How is it possible to do this while making the whole think arbitrarily scale-able? I need to be able to increase the size of the whole arrangement without affecting the internal positioning.

Comment: You can use weight inside your view and take Linear layout as parent layout

Comment: @NileshPanchal This appears to work although it's a tad inelegant. Does Android not have an easier way to precisely achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using weight sum

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"            
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/image_text"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Image "
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2.5"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This seems like the best answer since it scales well. Is there a more elegant way of positioning the inner textView that scales  with the parent sizes?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it is constraint layout, the TextView will in centre (Horizontally) of ImageView.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/iv_demo"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/iv_demo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/iv_demo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/iv_demo" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

If you want centre vertically also add one more line in TextView : `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/iv_demo"`